# python: pie chart font size

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

I'm plotting a pie chart using the following code:

```
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,12))
ax1.pie(data,
    labels=label,
    radius=1,
    startangle=90,
    colors=cols,
    counterclock=False,
    shadow=False,
    wedgeprops={'edgecolor': 'white', 'linewidth': 1},
    textprops={'fontsize': 8},
    pctdistance=0.85,
    autopct='%1.1f%%')

plt.title('Title', fontsize=16)
plt.tight_layout()
```

When I change the font size in textprops both the font size of the labels and the percentages change.

What I would like to do is use different font sizes for the labels and the percentages.

Comment: try this:`wdges, labels, autopct = ax1.pie(...);plt.setp(labels, fontsize=15)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I applied your code to the example in the official reference and added the code to change the font.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Pie chart, where the slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise:
l = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs'
sizes = [15, 30, 45, 10]
explode = (0, 0.1, 0, 0)  # only "explode" the 2nd slice (i.e. 'Hogs')
cols = ['C0','C1','C2','C3']

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,12))
wdges, labels, autopct = ax1.pie(sizes,
    labels=l,
    radius=1,
    startangle=90,
    colors=cols,
    counterclock=False,
    shadow=False,
    wedgeprops={'edgecolor': 'white', 'linewidth': 1},
    textprops={'fontsize': 8},
    pctdistance=0.85,
    autopct='%1.1f%%')

plt.setp(labels, fontsize=15) #update
plt.title('Title', fontsize=16)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]